# CSS file note working with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am a freshman to Codeigniter. I have made an HTML page of my design, and have splited them according to division tags. In the file name head.php(in views folder, i have added the CSS of my design. But my CSS is not working. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the URL you used for your CSS file? can you share with us.

Comment: How did u add it? If you've included css file,that should be placed properly

Comment: View page source, check if css path is building correctly or not

Comment: By not working, you mean the css styles are not applied? Have you tried looking at the page source if you can open the css file?

Comment: I have used it as my desigenr gave it to me. i hadnt made any changes.

Comment: We will need to see code in order to help you with this. If you can add the relevant parts to your question, flag it for moderator attention to be reviewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

in your view put this

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/your_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

then create  a folder under your ci folder

- ci folder

  - application
  - system
  - css - put your css in this folder

Answer (score 0):

Put the css file to base folder where index.php is stored and use it.if you want to store it somewhere else please use `base_url();` function in codeigniter http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html